# Do we say "it's sunny after rain" to mean "after hardship is happiness"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

See this situation

A country is in its worst economic crisis but after its worst it will get better. Just like in nature, when it is the darkest, it is time when it starts getting light.

We say this metaphor "**it's sunny after rain**" (translated literally in Vietnamese) which means "**after hardship is happiness**".

**Do we have a similar phrase like that in English?**

Comment: There's a saying "The darkest hour is just before the dawn."

Answer (score 1):

That is *almost* a recognisable idiom, but not quite.

"Sunshine always follows the rain", and some other variations of it, appears in poetry, song lyrics and other media. It isn't really a 'saying', but most English speakers would probably recognise its metaphorical meaning.

A more common idiom with a similar meaning is "there is light at the end of the tunnel", although some would argue this means the better time is in view. However, the phrase is often used by others to give hope to someone who perhaps cannot 'see' the better time ahead.

Also, we say that "every cloud has a silver lining" to mean that sad times can also come with an unexpected positive.

Comment: "There should be sunshine after rain" - Dire Straits, _Why Worry?_. But, as you say, I don't know it as a saying apart from song lyrics.

Comment: @ColinFine that would be one of the variations to which I referred.

Answer (score 0):

The most common answer would be "it's always darkest before the dawn," which is almost literally what you wrote in your first paragraph.